# Bash. Create var with name of parameter and clean its value

Tags: regex, bash, parameters

I want to create a var with a name of the param passed to the function. Is possible? And then filter it's content to remove possible spaces and single quotes before and after the data asked while read. Not working example:

```
function test() {
    read $1
    [[ ${1} =~ ^\'?(.*)(\'.*)?$ ]] && 1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
}

test "testingvar"
#At this point, the user sent some data to the read statement
echo $testingvar
```

For the data received in the read statement, we can receive some different strings. Let's check this 3 examples:

```
/path/file
'/path/file'
/path/file' <-notice a space after the quote
```

In all examples, the regexp must clean and let /path/file without possible quotes and spaces.... and as I said, all in a var called as the param of the function. Is a dream or can be done in bash? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and `${!name}` might be what you're after.  Note that in `read`, you normally specify the names without the `$` (e.g. `read -r value`) because you want to read into the variable, not into its current value.

Comment: `test` is a horrible name for a shell function... `test` is already a shell builtin in most modern shells.

Comment: yes, you are right. but in my real script it has another name. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
fun(){
    read -r "$1"
    declare -n var="$1" #use a nameref -- see `help declare`
    var=${var//[\' ]/}  #clean the contents with string substitution
}
fun testingvar <<<"/path/file"; echo "$testingvar"
fun testingvar <<<"'/path/file'"; echo "$testingvar"
fun testingvar <<<"  /path/ file'"; echo "$testingvar"
```

This outputs:

```
/path/file
/path/file
/path/file
```

I.e., all the inputs got cleaned up and put into the variable whose named was passed via `$1`.

---

**Namerefs:**

Basically, namerefs are like auto-dereferenced pointers except they point to variables instead of addresses. They can be used as both l-values and r-values, and they are always autodereferenced after they're created.

You can use namerefs to get around the fact that you can't assign to a *variable variable*, i.e. you can't do:

```
foo=bar
```

and then

```
$foo=42 #illegal
```

to assign 42 to `bar`, but you *can* do:

```
declare -n foo=bar
foo=42 #now bar is 42
```

**Edit:**
If you want to remove all single quote and spaces but only at the beginning and end, you can use `extglob`:

```
fun(){
    local settings="$(shopt -p extglob)" #save extglob settings
    shopt -s extglob #set extglob
    read -r "$1"
    declare -n var="$1" #use a nameref -- see `help declare`
    var=${var##+([ \'])}; var=${var%%+([ \'])}
    eval "$settings" #restore extglob settings
}
fun testingvar <<<"/path/file"; echo "$testingvar"
fun testingvar <<<"'/path/file'"; echo "$testingvar"
fun testingvar <<<"  /pa'th/ f'ile'"; echo "$testingvar"
```

**Edit 2 -- nameref-less version with eval:**

```
fun(){
    local settings="$(shopt -p extglob)" #save extglob settings
    shopt -s extglob #set extglob

    local var
    read -r var; var=${var##+([ \'])}; var=${var%%+([ \'])}
    eval "$1=\$var" #avoids interpolating the var value for eval to avoid code injections via stdin

    eval "$settings" #restore extglob settings
}
fun testingvar <<<"/path/file"; echo "$testingvar"
fun testingvar <<<"'/path/file'"; echo "$testingvar"
fun testingvar <<<"  /pa'th/ f'ile'"; echo "$testingvar"
```

Comment: very good! but the substitution is not valid to me. It clears the spaces... and I need to clean the spaces only before and after the data. The path could contain spaces and should not be removed.

Comment: One may note, namerefs (`declare -n`) are available in `bash` 4.3+ only.

Comment: I have bash 4.3, no problem. Thanks for the advice... @PSkocik the last script you wrote using extglob is failing.... I copy pasted it to try but errors appear!

Comment: Sorry @PSkocik, it seems to work, but only in my big script... not in an little example file test.sh only with that... why??

Comment: I've tested the example in the edit. It should work. I'm on bash 4.3.11. Have you made sure your test.sh runs with bash rather than something else? You either need to run it with `bash test.sh` or, if you execute it directly with `./test.sh`, your shebang line must be one of `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's fully working... but finally the minimum version of bash 4.3 is going to be a problem... :/ any alternative for 4.2?

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Evil old evals. :) Second edit added.

Comment: Wow... amazing @PSkocik. I'm learning bash to know like you someday! :) good alternative to use with bash 4.2 now my script can be more compatible. Thanks.